# Swift 3: button on collectionview

Tags: swift, button, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I added a button to my prototype cell of UICollectionView and I want to update a property showed in a label of the cell:

[image: There's a button over the 28 and I want when taped add 1 to this integer]

Thank's a lot

EDIT:
Probably need to create a function who also get the indexPath.row but don't know how do this.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    //var cell :CounterCollectionViewCell!
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CounterCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    let myColor :UIColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 179/255, blue: 28/255, alpha: 1.0)
    let presentCounter = counters[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = presentCounter.nameCD
    cell.valueLabel.text = String(presentCounter.valueCD)
    cell.backgroundColor = myColor
    cell.layer.cornerRadius=10

    return cell
}

@IBAction func masterCellAction() {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on cellForItem add the action as a selector to your custom button which you added to your custom cell like this

cell?.customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(masterCellAction), for: .touchUpInside)

Edit:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 cell.masterButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(masterAction(_:)),for: .touchUpInside) 
return cell 
} 
func masterAction(_ sender: UIButton) 
{ 
    let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: ((sender.superview?.superview) as! CounterCollectionViewCell))

let presentCounter = counters[indexPath.row] presentCounter.valueCD = presentCounter.valueCD + 1 
}
```

Comment: and add indexPath to the masterCellAction if you need that

Comment: Thank's a lot but how can I add indexPath to the masterAction please ?

Comment: @IBAction func masterCellAction(indexpath : IndexPath) {

}

Comment: and since that is a selector it knows where to get the indexPath, but the #selector code will change to #selector(masterCellAction(:)) or (_:) too, change the func first, the autocomplete will do the rest

Comment: Get an error in the console "unrecognized selector sent to instance"                 `override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    [...]
    
    cell.masterButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(masterAction(indexPath:)),for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return cell
}

func masterAction(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let presentCounter = counters[indexPath.row]
    presentCounter.valueCD = presentCounter.valueCD + 1
}`

Comment: that means you typed the name of the selector wrong, did you let the xcode completion suggestion do it's job? do it like below

Comment: cell.masterButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(masterAction(_:)),for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: func masterAction(_ indexPath : IndexPath) {//do your stuff here}

Comment: That's exactly what i wrote, copy paste for sur and the error is already there

Comment: there is an underline _ that stack overflow don't show
let me edit my answer

Comment: can you mail me your project? lvloh3n@gmail.com

Comment: i've sent you the email

Comment: sorry, my bad, fixed the issue and edited my answer, selector expected the button not the indexPath, you had to extract the indexPath from the button inside the selector like above

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have 2 solutions like these:

1. Create your own cell's class. That means the button will handle tap event itself. By this way, you need to create a new UICollectionViewCell subclass.
2. Assume that when user select the cell (I mean user can tap any where in the cell), you just need to implement didSelectAtCell function, handle the cell by indexPath.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom class (eg. CustomButton) which inherits UIButton and add a property indexPath of type NSIndexPath. Then, make all your buttons of type CustomButton and you can easily know which cell you are updating.